# VS2008 - Front Page Server Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2008, frontpage

Good day,

I'm looking for a layman's explanation of the relationship betweeen FrontPage Server Extensions and a .NET web app.

Background:
A team of us are using VS2008 to develop a web app which is located on a network server. This is an internal project - we're all on the same domain. I created the site on the server and made sure everyone had sufficient file system permissions on that server. However, when they attempted to open the site through VS they were prompted for a user name and password. I don't understand what they were being asked to authenticate to - they already had the necessary file system permissions. We know this because they were able to browse to the site and create folders/files, delete folders/files, whatever.

After googling around, I came up with the fact that I needed to add them to the "Author" role in the FrontPage Server Extensions 2002 Administration page through VS. After, I did this, all was well.

It seems to me these permissions have nothing to do with the file system permissions on the server, the IIS service, or the website. It seems to me these permissions have nothing to do with anything, but I'm obviously mistaken.

I'm looking for a little history on what's going on behind the scenes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this link for the Security Issues: http://docs.sun.com/source/816-5666-10/esapmsfp.htm

If you installed the extensions after you had configured the permissions, you may have to replace the ACL's on those files by resetting the permissions for the project's folder because of the *vti** folders and files it creates within the web application itself; it resets the permissions for those folders and will remove the permissions you have set. Also, it may map your application's _vti_bin folder to the program files folder location. I know the answer is kinda late, but better late than never I always tell her!

Would recommend TFS source control development over doing development using a UNC shared path.